# What is the correct way to use ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) re: largeTitle?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm a bit confused on how to use **ToolbarItem(placement: .principal)**

The navigation bar is large (by default), but .principle just top-centers the title, with lots of space beneath (I assumed using this placement, the label would auto-adjust - and appear 'large title' style because of the size of the bar).

Using .navigationTitle("My Title") uses the large title but creates a constraints conflict.

What are the sizing recommendations for .toolbar(content:) and ToolbarItem()?

```
   ...
        .toolbar(content: {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                            VStack {
                                Text("My Title")
                }
            }
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                Button("+") {
                    print("Add something!")
                }
                }
        })
```

Xcode 12.3.

Answer (score 4):

Navigation bar title and navigation bar item are different things. You just use second one with text (and name it title, but it is not actually navigation bar title).

To hide large navigation bar title use inline mode for it and then toolbar

```
  ...
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    .toolbar(content: {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
  ...
```

Comment: I'd like to know how to use large title correctly too?